# Find specific differences between multiple dates with same key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm fetching some elements from an SQL statement, and putting them in an array.

What I want to do is to find specific differences between the dates of those elements in the array, and add them to another array.

The results from the database looks like this (key=>value):

```
array(
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:47:16", 
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:47:00", 
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:46:50",  
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:42:50", 
    "20"=>"13-02-2013 09:30:50", 
    "20"=>"13-02-2013 09:20:50", 
    "30"=>"13-02-2013 09:10:15"
);
```

I need to find those elements, with the same ID (key), where the difference between the dates are less than 60 seconds. For instance, I want an output looking this:

```
array(
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:47:16", 
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:47:00", 
    "10"=>"13-02-2013 09:46:50"
);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't have elements with the same key in ordinally array.

Comment: As abc says, it's not possible to have an array like that. So show us what you really have.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do it then?

Comment: I'll show output in a minute

Comment: For the correct way, use `DateTime` and a foreach loop, and **prefix** each key with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

An array can't have the same key for more than one time. Every element has unique key.
Whenever you will try to read this array, it will show :

```
Array
(
[10] => 13-02-2013 09:42:50
[20] => 13-02-2013 09:20:50
[30] => 13-02-2013 09:10:15
)
```

If you want to retrieve all the elements with key '10', you'll have to use multidimensional array while retrieving data from database something like that .

```
$new_arr = array();
// Put database data object in place of $arr
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(array_key_exists($k,$new_arr)){
        $new_arr[$k][] = $v;
    }
    else{
        $new_arr[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Here $new_arr will be in the form of :

```
$new_arr = array("10"=> array([0] => '13-02-2013 09:47:16'),
                        array([1] => '13-02-2013 09:47:00'),
                        array([2] => '13-02-2013 09:46:50'),
                 "20" => '',
                  ........
               )
```

And then you can pick the values whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

uhm i quote abc667 and Jon, however if you wanna compare dates you can scan all the array with a simple for and compare the current date in the array and the next.. if u use a for with a variable called $cont, if $cont = 1 the first date is $array[1] ($array[$cont]) and the second is $array[2] ($array[$cont+1]).
Ive done a simple example (ivent seen if it run, but i hope that ;P)
look that your array is called **$array_dates** in my example and ivent created the new array, but its simple, you add it in the for cycle.

```
<?php

// example >>> $array_dates[1] = '2013-2-13 12:30:00'; 

// scan all the array with the date
for ($cont=0; $cont<count($array_dates); $cont++)
    {
    $date_1 = $array_dates[$cont];
    $date_2 = $array_dates[$cont+1];

list($data1,$His1) = explode(' ',$date_1); 
list($year1,$month1,$day1) = explode('-',$data1); 
list($hour1,$min1,$sec1) = explode(':',$His1); 

list($data2,$His2) = explode(' ',$date_2); 
list($year2,$month2,$day2) = explode('-',$data2); 
list($hour2,$min2,$sec2) = explode(':',$His2); 

$diff=mktime($hour2,$min2,$sec2,$month2,$day2,$year2)-mktime($hour1,$min1,$sec1,$month1,$day1,$year1); 

$diff = mktime($hour2, $min2,$sec2, $month2,$day2,$year2) - mktime($hour1,$min1,$sec1, $month1,$day1,$year1); 

$diff1  = floor($diff % (60*60*24)); 
$diff2  = floor($diff1 % (60*60)) ; 
$sec    = $diff2 % 60; 


echo "<br>Seconds difference from <u>$date_1</u> and <u>$date_2</u>: <em>$sec</em><br>";

} //end of the for cycle
?>
```

i hope you will appreciate it,
best regards.

EDIT:

### you have to put the month in the format ive put, 'cause mktime make trouble with zero before the number (it thinks is octal!)... however you can read date format in php.net